# The VM does not support the attach mechanism

Tags: java

I am trying to attach to a vm. Code:

```
VirtualMachine attach = VirtualMachine.attach(String.valueOf(id));
attach.loadAgent(file.getAbsolutePath() , args);
```

Error:

```
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: The VM does not support the attach mechanism
at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotAttachProvider.testAttachable(HotSpotAttachProvider.java:162)
at sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(WindowsAttachProvider.java:67)
at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
```

Any clues on how can I fix it?

Comment: I think the biggest clue is [The VM does not support the attach mechanism](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/tools/attach/HotSpotAttachProvider.java#L137).

Comment: Can you attach to it with visualvm?